# How to get the owner of a SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

When querying the Graph for a SharePoint site, the json does not include the owner information.

I found a way workaround to get the owner information, but is it possible to get the owner of the SharePoint site without first querying the default drive?

Workaround:

1. call `/sites/{site-id}/drive`
2. Fetch the drive owner

Answer (score 1):

[`Site` resource](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/site) does not expose `Owner` property and indeed it could be retrieved via `Site.Drive` property. But it is not necessarily to request drive resource *separately*, the following options are available:

**Option 1**

Modify your query to request `site` source along with default `drive` resource via a *single* request  (using [`expand` parameter](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#expand-parameter))

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root?select=*,drive&expand=drive
```

**Option 2**

Combine *multiple* (e.g. [get site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/site_get) and [get drive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/drive_get)) requests using [JSON batching](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json


{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/sites/root"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/sites/root/drive"
    }
  ]
}
```